# Small generic helper library for working with recursive data structures

Tags: rust, library

I've written a small rust library that solves rust's problems with using recursive data types (e.g, linked lists).

using the library, you can use `RecRef<'_, List>`, and use it to travel up and down your list dynamically and safely at will.

It uses unsafe primitives but uses a clever trick to present to the user a safe interface.

It's the first library I've ever published, and I worked hard on it. However, I would appreciate general feedback about the library. Specifically, I'm most interested in:

- Does the library conform to programming conventions?
- Is the documentation clear?
- Is the code safe? I'm sure the general idea is correct, but rust's unsafe code can be quite hairy, and maybe I missed an edge case, perhaps regarding the `Send` instance.

For consistency with future readers, this is version 0.2.0 of the library, `recursive_reference`.

links:

- [repository](https://github.com/noamtashma/recursive_reference)
- [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/recursive_reference/0.2.0)
- [documentation](https://docs.rs/recursive_reference/0.2.0/recursive_reference/)
- [a complicated example usage](https://github.com/noamtashma/orchard/blob/master/src/trees/basic_tree/walker.rs)

license:
the library is dual licensed under MIT and APACHE-2.0.

the library's code:

````rust
    //! Recursive reference.
    //!
    //!This crate provides a way to traverse recursive structures easily and safely.
    //!Rust's lifetime rules will usually force you to either only walk forward through the structure,
    //!or use recursion, calling your method recursively every time you go down a node,
    //!and returning every time you want to go back up, which leads to terrible code.
    //!
    //!Instead, you can use the [`RecRef`] type, to safely and dynamically walk up
    //!and down your recursive structure.
    //!
    //!# Examples
    //!
    //! Say we have a recursive linked list structure
    //! ----------------------------------------------
    //!```rust
    //!enum List<T> {
    //!    Root(Box<Node<T>>),
    //!    Empty,
    //!}
    //!struct Node<T> {
    //!    value: T,
    //!    next: List<T>,
    //!}
    //!```
    //!
    //! We can use a [`RecRef`] directly
    //! ----------------------------------------------
    //!```rust
    //! # enum List<T> {
    //! # Root(Box<Node<T>>),
    //! # Empty,
    //! # }
    //! # struct Node<T> {
    //! # value: T,
    //! # next: List<T>,
    //! # }
    //! use recursive_reference::*;
    //!
    //! fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    //!     let node1 = Node { value : 5, next : List::Empty };
    //!     let mut node2 = Node { value : 2, next : List::Root(Box::new(node1)) };
    //!
    //!     let mut rec_ref = RecRef::new(&mut node2);
    //!     assert_eq!(rec_ref.value, 2); // rec_ref is a smart pointer to the current node
    //!     rec_ref.value = 7; // change the value at the head of the list
    //!     RecRef::extend_result(&mut rec_ref, |node| match &mut node.next {
    //!         List::Root(next_node) => Ok(next_node),
    //!         List::Empty => Err(()),
    //!     })?;
    //!     assert_eq!(rec_ref.value, 5);
    //!     // extend the RecRef
    //!     let res = RecRef::extend_result(&mut rec_ref, |node| match &mut node.next {
    //!         List::Root(next_node) => Ok(next_node),
    //!         List::Empty => Err(()),
    //!     });
    //!     assert_eq!(res, Err(())); // could not go forward because it reached the end of the list
    //!     assert_eq!(rec_ref.value, 5);
    //!     let last = RecRef::pop(&mut rec_ref).ok_or(())?;
    //!     assert_eq!(last.value, 5);
    //!     assert_eq!(rec_ref.value, 7) ; // moved back to the head of the list because we popped rec_ref
    //!     Ok(())
    //! }
    //!```
    //!
    //! We can also wrap a [`RecRef`] in a walker struct
    //! ----------------------------------------------
    //! Note: this time we are using a `RecRef<List<T>>` and not a `RecRef<Node<T>>`, to allow pointing
    //! at the empty end of the list.
    //!```rust
    //! # enum List<T> {
    //! # Root(Box<Node<T>>),
    //! # Empty,
    //! # }
    //! # struct Node<T> {
    //! # value: T,
    //! # next: List<T>,
    //! # }
    //! use recursive_reference::*;
    //! struct Walker<'a, T> {
    //!     rec_ref : RecRef<'a, List<T>>
    //! }
    //! impl<'a, T> Walker<'a, T> {
    //!     pub fn new(list: &'a mut List<T>) -> Self {
    //!         Walker {
    //!             rec_ref : RecRef::new(list)
    //!         }
    //!     }
    //!
    //!     /// Returns `None` when at the tail end of the list
    //!     pub fn next(&mut self) -> Option<()> {
    //!         RecRef::extend_result(&mut self.rec_ref, |current| match current {
    //!             List::Empty => Err(()),
    //!             List::Root(node) => Ok(&mut node.next),
    //!         }).ok()
    //!     }
    //!
    //!     /// Returns `None` when at the head of the list
    //!     pub fn prev(&mut self) -> Option<()> {
    //!         RecRef::pop(&mut self.rec_ref)?;
    //!         Some(())
    //!     }
    //!
    //!     /// Returns `None` when at the tail end of the list
    //!     pub fn value_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut T> {
    //!         match &mut *self.rec_ref {
    //!             List::Root(node) => Some(&mut node.value),
    //!             List::Empty => None,
    //!         }
    //!     }
    //! }
    //!
    //! fn main() -> Result<(), ()> {
    //!     let node1 = Node { value : 5, next : List::Empty };
    //!     let node2 = Node { value : 2, next : List::Root(Box::new(node1)) };
    //!     let mut list = List::Root(Box::new(node2));
    //!
    //!     let mut walker = Walker::new(&mut list);
    //!     assert_eq!(walker.value_mut().cloned(), Some(2));
    //!     *walker.value_mut().ok_or(())? = 7;
    //!     walker.next().ok_or(())?;
    //!     assert_eq!(walker.value_mut().cloned(), Some(5));
    //!     walker.next().ok_or(())?;
    //!     assert_eq!(walker.value_mut().cloned(), None); // end of the list
    //!     walker.prev().ok_or(())?;
    //!     assert_eq!(walker.value_mut().cloned(), Some(5));
    //!     walker.prev().ok_or(())?;
    //!     assert_eq!(walker.value_mut().cloned(), Some(7)); // we changed the value at the head
    //!     Ok(())
    //! }
    //!```
    //! With a [`RecRef`] you can
    //! ----------------------------------------------
    //! * Use the current reference (i.e, the top reference).
    //!  the [`RecRef`] is a smart pointer to it.
    //! * Freeze the current reference
    //!  and extend the [`RecRef`] with a new reference derived from it, using [`extend`][RecRef::extend] and similar functions.
    //!  for example, push to the stack a reference to the child of the current node.
    //! * Pop the stack to get back to the previous reference, unfreezing it.
    //!
    //! # Safety
    //! The [`RecRef`] type is implemented using unsafe rust, but provides a safe interface.
    //! The [`RecRef`] methods' types guarantee that the references will always have a legal lifetime
    //! and will respect rust's borrow rules, even if that lifetime is not known in advance.
    //!
    //! The [`RecRef`] obeys rust's borrowing rules, by simulating freezing. Whenever
    //! you extend a [`RecRef`] with a reference `child_ref` that is derived from the current
    //! reference `parent_ref`, the [`RecRef`] freezes `parent_ref`, and no longer allows
    //! `parent_ref` to be used.
    //! When `child_ref` will be popped from the [`RecRef`],
    //! `parent_ref` will be allowed to be used again.
    //!
    //! This is essentially the same as what would have happened if you wrote your functions recursively,
    //! but it's decoupled from the actual call stack.
    //!
    //! Another important point to consider is the safety of
    //! the actual call to [`extend`][RecRef::extend]: see its documentation.
    #![no_std]
    #![doc(html_root_url = "https://docs.rs/recursive_reference/0.2.0/recursive_reference/")]

    extern crate alloc;
    use alloc::vec::*;

    use core::marker::PhantomData;
    use core::ops::Deref;
    use core::ops::DerefMut;
    use void::ResultVoidExt;

    /// A Recursive reference.
    /// This struct is used to allow recursively reborrowing mutable references in a dynamic
    /// but safe way.
    ///
    /// `RecRef<'a, T>` represents a reference to a value of type `T`, with lifetime `'a`,
    /// which can move recursively into and out of its subfields of the same type `T`.
    ///
    /// With a [`RecRef`] you can
    /// ----------------------------------------------
    /// * Use the current reference (i.e, the top reference).
    ///  the [`RecRef`] is a smart pointer to it.
    /// * Freeze the current reference
    ///  and extend the [`RecRef`] with a new reference derived from it, using [`extend`][RecRef::extend] and similar functions.
    ///  for example, push to the stack a reference to the child of the current node.
    /// * Pop the stack to get back to the previous reference, unfreezing it.
    ///
    /// The methods' types guarantee that the references will always have a legal lifetime
    /// and will respect rust's borrow rules, even if that lifetime is not known in advance.
    ///
    /// Internally, the [`RecRef`] stores a [`Vec`] of pointers, that it extends and pops from.
    pub struct RecRef<'a, T: ?Sized> {
        head: *mut T,
        vec: Vec<*mut T>,
        phantom: PhantomData<&'a mut T>,
    }

    // TODO: consider converting the pointers to values without checking for null values.
    // it's supposed to work, since the pointers only ever come from references.
    // otherwise, when 1.53 rolls out, convert to `NonNull`.

    // these aren't ever supposed to happen. but since we touch unsafe code, we might as well
    // have clear error message when we `expect()`
    const NULL_POINTER_ERROR: &str = "error! somehow got null pointer";

    impl<'a, T: ?Sized> RecRef<'a, T> {
        /// Creates a new RecRef containing only a single reference.
        pub fn new(r: &'a mut T) -> Self {
            RecRef {
                head: r as *mut T,
                vec: Vec::new(),
                phantom: PhantomData,
            }
        }

        /// Returns the size of `rec_ref`, i.e, the amount of references in it.
        /// It increases every time you extend `rec_ref`, and decreases every time you pop
        /// `rec_ref`.
        /// The size of a new [`RecRef`] is always `1`.
        pub fn size(rec_ref: &Self) -> usize {
            rec_ref.vec.len() + 1
        }

        /// This function extends `rec_ref` one time. If the current
        /// reference is `current_ref: &mut T`, then this call extends `rec_ref`
        /// with the new reference `ref2: &mut T = func(current_ref)`.
        /// After this call, `rec_ref` will expose the new `ref2`, and `current_ref`
        /// will be frozen (As it is borrowed by `ref2`), until `ref2` is
        /// popped off, unfreezing `current_ref`.
        ///
        /// # Safety:
        /// Pay close attention to the type of `func`: we require that
        /// `F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> &'b mut T`. That is, for every lifetime `'b`,
        /// we require that `F: FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> &'b mut T`.
        ///
        /// Let's define `'freeze_time` to be the time `ref2` will be in the [`RecRef`].
        /// That is, `'freeze_time`
        /// is the time for which `ref2` will live, and the lifetime in which `current_ref`
        /// will be frozen by `ref2`. Then, the type of `func` should have been
        /// `FnOnce(&'freeze_time mut T) -> &'freeze_time mut T`. If that woudld have been the type
        /// of `func`, the code would've followed rust's borrowing rules correctly.
        ///
        /// However, we can't know yet what that
        /// lifetime is: it will be whatever amount of time passes until the programmer decides
        /// to pop `ref2` out of the [`RecRef`]. And that hasn't even been decided at this point.
        /// Whatever lifetime `'freeze_time` that turns out to be, we will know
        /// after-the-fact that the type of `func` should have been
        /// `FnOnce(&'freeze_time mut T) -> &'freeze_time mut T`.
        ///
        /// Therefore, the solution is to require that `func` will be able to work with any value of
        /// `'freeze_time`. Then we can be
        /// sure that the code would've worked correctly if we put the correct lifetime there.
        /// Therefore, we can always pick correct lifetimes after-the-fact, so the code must be safe.
        ///
        /// Also note:
        /// The type ensures that the current reference can't be leaked outside of `func`.
        /// `func` can't guarantee that
        /// `current_ref` will live for any length of time, so it can't store it outside anywhere
        /// or give it to anything.
        /// It can only use `current_ref` while still inside `func`,
        /// and use it in order to return `ref2`, which is the
        /// intended usage.
        pub fn extend<F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F)
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> &'b mut T,
        {
            Self::extend_result(rec_ref, |r| Ok(func(r))).void_unwrap()
        }

        /// Same as [`Self::extend`], but allows the function to return an error value.
        pub fn extend_result<E, F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F) -> Result<(), E>
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> Result<&'b mut T, E>,
        {
            Self::extend_result_precise(rec_ref, |r, _phantom| func(r))
        }

        /// Same as [`Self::extend`], but allows the function to return an error value,
        /// and also tells the inner function that `'a : 'b` using a phantom argument.
        pub fn extend_result_precise<E, F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F) -> Result<(), E>
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T, PhantomData<&'b &'a ()>) -> Result<&'b mut T, E>,
        {
            // The compiler is told explicitly that the lifetime is `'a`.
            // Otherwise the minimal lifetime possible is chosen.
            // It probably doesn't matter, since we specifically require `func` to be able to work
            // with any lifetime, and the references are converted to pointers immediately.
            // However, that is the "most correct" lifetime - the reference's actual lifetime may
            // be anything up to `'a`,
            // depending on whether the user will pop it earlier than that.
            let head_ref: &'a mut T = unsafe { rec_ref.head.as_mut() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR);

            match func(head_ref, PhantomData) {
                Ok(p) => {
                    Self::push(rec_ref, p);
                    Ok(())
                }
                Err(e) => Err(e),
            }
        }

        /// This function maps the top of the [`RecRef`]. It's similar to [`Self::extend`], but
        /// it replaces the current reference instead of keeping it. See [`Self::extend`] for more details.
        pub fn map<F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F)
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> &'b mut T,
        {
            Self::map_result(rec_ref, |r| Ok(func(r))).void_unwrap()
        }

        /// Same as [`Self::map`], but allows the function to return an error value.
        pub fn map_result<E, F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F) -> Result<(), E>
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T) -> Result<&'b mut T, E>,
        {
            Self::map_result_precise(rec_ref, |r, _| func(r))
        }

        /// Same as [`Self::map`], but allows the function to return an error value,
        /// and also tells the inner function that `'a : 'b` using a phantom argument.
        pub fn map_result_precise<E, F>(rec_ref: &mut Self, func: F) -> Result<(), E>
        where
            F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T, PhantomData<&'b &'a ()>) -> Result<&'b mut T, E>,
        {
            // The compiler is told explicitly that the lifetime is `'a`.
            // Otherwise the minimal lifetime possible is chosen.
            // It probably doesn't matter, since we specifically require `func` to be able to work
            // with any lifetime, and the references are converted to pointers immediately.
            // However, that is the "most correct" lifetime - the reference's actual lifetime may
            // be anything up to `'a`,
            // depending on whether the user will pop it earlier than that.
            let head_ref: &'a mut T = unsafe { rec_ref.head.as_mut() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR);

            match func(head_ref, PhantomData) {
                Ok(p) => {
                    rec_ref.head = p as *mut T;
                    Ok(())
                }
                Err(e) => Err(e),
            }
        }

        /// Push another reference to the [`RecRef`], unrelated to the current one.
        /// `rec_ref.push(new_ref)` is morally equivalent to `rec_ref.extend_result_precise(move |_, _| { Ok(new_ref) })`.
        /// However, you might have some trouble making the anonymous function conform to the
        /// right type.
        pub fn push(rec_ref: &mut Self, r: &'a mut T) {
            rec_ref.vec.push(rec_ref.head);
            rec_ref.head = r as *mut T;

            /* alternative definition using a call to `extend_result_precise`.
            // in order to name 'x, replace the signature with:
            // pub fn push<'x>(rec_ref: &'x mut Self, r : &'a mut T) {
            // this is used in order to tell the closure to conform to the right type
            fn helper<'a,'x, T : ?Sized, F> (f : F) -> F where
                    F : for<'b> FnOnce(&'b mut T, PhantomData<&'b &'a ()>)
                    -> Result<&'b mut T, void::Void> + 'x
                { f }

            Self::extend_result_precise(rec_ref,
                helper::<'a,'x>(move |_, _phantom| { Ok(r) })
            ).void_unwrap();
            */
        }

        /// Lets the user use the last reference for some time, and discards it completely.
        /// After the user uses it, the next time they inspect the [`RecRef`], it won't be there.
        /// If the [`RecRef`] has only one reference left, this returns `None`, because
        /// the [`RecRef`] can't be empty.
        pub fn pop(rec_ref: &mut Self) -> Option<&mut T> {
            let res = unsafe { rec_ref.head.as_mut() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR);
            rec_ref.head = rec_ref.vec.pop()?; // We can't pop the original reference. In that case, Return None.
            Some(res)
        }

        /// Discards the [`RecRef`] and returns the last reference.
        /// The difference between this and using [`Self::pop`] are:
        /// * This will consume the [`RecRef`]
        /// * [`Self::pop`] will never pop the first original reference, because that would produce an
        ///   invalid [`RecRef`]. [`Self::into_ref`] will.
        pub fn into_ref(rec_ref: Self) -> &'a mut T {
            unsafe { rec_ref.head.as_mut() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR)
        }
    }

    /// [`RecRef<T>`] represents a reference to a value of type `T`,
    /// which can move recursively into and out of its subfields of the same type `T`.
    /// Therefore, it implements `Deref` and `DerefMut` with `Item=T`.
    impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Deref for RecRef<'a, T> {
        type Target = T;
        fn deref(&self) -> &T {
            unsafe { self.head.as_ref() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR)
        }
    }

    /// [`RecRef<T>`] represents a reference to a value of type `T`,
    /// which can move recursively into and out of its subfields of the same type `T`.
    /// Therefore, it implements `Deref` and `DerefMut` with `Item=T`.
    impl<'a, T: ?Sized> DerefMut for RecRef<'a, T> {
        fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
            unsafe { self.head.as_mut() }.expect(NULL_POINTER_ERROR)
        }
    }

    impl<'a, Q: ?Sized, T: ?Sized + AsRef<Q>> AsRef<Q> for RecRef<'a, T> {
        fn as_ref(&self) -> &Q {
            AsRef::as_ref(&**self)
        }
    }

    impl<'a, Q: ?Sized, T: ?Sized + AsMut<Q>> AsMut<Q> for RecRef<'a, T> {
        fn as_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Q {
            AsMut::as_mut(&mut **self)
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T: ?Sized> From<&'a mut T> for RecRef<'a, T> {
        fn from(r: &'a mut T) -> Self {
            Self::new(r)
        }
    }

    /// # Safety:
    /// Behaviorally, A [`RecRef`] is the same as `&'a mut T`, and
    /// should be [`Send`] for the same reason. Additionally, it contains a [`Vec`].
    /// The [`Send`] instance for [`Vec`] contains the bound `A: Send` for the allocator type `A`,
    /// so we should require that as well. However, we don't have direct access to the
    /// default allocator type. So instead we require `Vec<&'a mut T>: Send`.
    unsafe impl<'a, T: ?Sized + Send> Send for RecRef<'a, T> where Vec<&'a mut T>: Send {}

    /// # Safety:
    /// Behaviorally, A [`RecRef`] is the same as `&'a mut T`, and
    /// should be [`Sync`] for the same reason. Additionally, it contains a [`Vec`].
    /// The [`Sync`] instance for [`Vec`] contains the bound `A: Sync` for the allocator type `A`,
    /// so we should require that as well. However, we don't have direct access to the
    /// default allocator type. So instead we require `Vec<&'a mut T>: Sync`.
    unsafe impl<'a, T: ?Sized + Sync> Sync for RecRef<'a, T> where Vec<&'a mut T>: Sync {}
````

Cargo.toml:

```
    [package]
    name = "recursive_reference"
    version = "0.2.0" # remember to bump the html_root_url as well
    authors = ["Noam Ta Shma <noam.tashma@gmail.com>"]
    edition = "2018"
    keywords = ["recursive", "data-structures", "smart-pointer", "reference"]
    categories = ["rust-patterns", "data-structures", "no-std"]
    description = "This crate provides a way to walk on recursive structures easily and safely."
    readme = "README.md"
    repository = "https://github.com/noamtashma/recursive_reference"
    license = "MIT OR Apache-2.0"

    # See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

    [dependencies]
    void = "1.0"

    [lib]
    name = "recursive_reference"
    path = "src/lib.rs"
```

The README.md file contains about the same information as the documentation in
the library itself.